# Django - Get Value Only from queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

When the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values) discuss values() and values_list(), or any query for that matter, they always require that you know what you are looking for, i.e.,

```
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('headline', flat=True).get(pk=1)
'First entry'
```

What about the situation where you need a value from a specific field, whether on this model or a foreign key, but you don't know the pk or the value in the specified field, *and you don't care*, you just need whatever is there. How do you query for it?

Alternatively, if I use this example from the docs:

```
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
<QuerySet [1, 2, 3, ...]>
```

Could I add slice notation to the end of the query? But even then, I might not know in advance which slice I need. In other words, how to dynamically get a value from a specified field without knowing in advance what it or its pk is? Thx.

Comment: Adding some sample data and expected result may help to understand the requirement in a better way.

Comment: How do you know when you've got the _"value from a specified field"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending your scenario (*this time a simple query*) you have many of options to do it. One is to use a variable as field name. Then, feed that variable dynamically:

```
>>> field='headline'
>>> Entry.objects.values_list(field, flat=True).get(pk=1)
'First entry'

>>> field='body'
>>> Entry.objects.values_list(field, flat=True).get(pk=1)
'First entry body'
```

In order to slice results use offset/limit as follows:

```
Entry.objects.all()[offset:limit]

>>> field='headline'
>>> Entry.objects.values_list(field, flat=True)[5:10]
```